# Make IE behave like Firefox

Tags: html, cross-browser, libraries

i was wondering... 
when we design websites... there are cross-browser compatibility and browsers different behavior to HTML is an issue... designer has to check his design and work for cross-browser design consistency....

can we do somthing about it like add some libraries\scripts to the code so that one browser bahaves like other, so this is an easy guess i want `IEs` to behave like `Firefox`... like scripts are available for IE6's Transparent PNG problem...

Comment: There are libraries that "assist" in crossbrowser support (Like Jquery) but you can NOT make an outdated browser that needs to be got rid of, act like a more modern browser that actually works ;)

Comment: If it was that easy then "Use FoxIE" would be a more common answer on Stackoverflow then "use jQuery".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery has certainly made the task a LOT more manageable. I regularly have to affirm my code works on several versions of ALL major browsers. (Fortunately no longer IE6). jQuery team tests against all these browsers and provides a framework that does much to take care of most scripting and event handling differences.

```
Firefox 2.0+
Internet Explorer 6+
Safari 3+
Opera 9+
Chrome 1+
```

You should also be using a [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) that helps to initialize browsers to a more compatible state